# WithOrigins partially overrides Access-Control-Allow-Origin .NetCore API

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Startup.cs I have

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://acme.com"));
```

In my web.config I have

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip, deflate, sdch" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>        
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin..." />
```

When I submit an ajax request like this it tells me I that ACAO only allows one value, I have multiple "https://acme.com, *".

When I remove the values section completely, same error, but instead of listing my origins, it starts listing the values from the Allow-Access-Control-Headers tag.

When I remove the ACAO tag completely, it understandable tells me there is no tag.

What is the ACAO tag supposed to look like if I have a `WithOrigins` specification in my config?

Comment: It would be useful if you updated your question to also include a code snippet that shows the client-side JavaScript code for the request you’re trying to send. It would also help if pasted in verbatim, as a blockquote, the exact error message you’re seeing in the browser console in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn’t clear about what origins you actually want to allow. It seems your choices are:

- If you want to allow just `https://acme.com`, then you can drop the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>` line from your `web.config` and the server will still send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://acme.com` response header.
- If you want to allow all origins, `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)` is what you want to use instead—and that case too you want to also drop just the line with 
  `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>` from your `web.config`, since the server will already send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow all origins.

---

You can also specify the allowed headers in your `app.UseCors` call, like this:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://acme.com")
                              .WithHeaders("Authorization", "Location"));
```

Note that you shouldn’t need to specify the `Origin` header there, because browsers don’t require `Origin` to be in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in order for it to be allowed. (Because the `Origin` header is set and sent by the browser itself in requests; it’s not a “custom” header.)

If you just want to allow all request headers, you can instead do this:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://acme.com")
                              .AllowAnyHeader());
```

If you use either `.WithHeaders(…)` or `.AllowAnyHeader()` headers there, you can then also drop the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin..."/>` line from `web.config`

Comment: I have tried all of those combinations while dropping the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>` and I get preflight request errors on the ajax call stating that "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `https://acme.com` is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I want to allow specific origins. I definitely do not want to allow any origins.

Comment: You say that in some case you get a console message about the ACAO header having the multiple values "`https://acme.com`" & "`*`". So that’d seem to mean your  `app.UseCors` call is working, ’cause that’s the only place you’ve specified `https://acme.com`, right? So dropping `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>` should eliminate the problem of `*` getting added to the ACAO value. But it sounds like it’s instead just causing the browser to give you a different error? It would help to see the exact error messages, with your question explaining the steps that cause each error case

Answer (score 1):

This was actually someone else's project, so I'm not sure where the web.config entry came from to begin with. I deleted the `<httpprotocol>` section of the web config entirely and got the `AddCors()` to work by using the normal process of:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://acme.com");
        });
```

It seems as though having an `<httpProtocol>` tag in the web.config was causing it to look in a two places for information that was only supposed to be present once.